# How to extract multiple curves from surface?

Tags: curve-modifier

I'm trying to create a model of a fishing net and in order to achieve a deeper level of detail I modelled a small section of the rope that makes the fishing net. I then wanted to create a group of curves that the rope section can follow (curve modifier). Is there a way to extract the subdivide curves of the final shape of the net instead of creating every single curve?

Comment: Image would have been helpful here. You may use wireframe modifier for this? If you want few of them then shift select edges and duplicate them and while being in edit mode, you may separate them using P command!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: What worked from the above?

Comment: Selecting the edges in edit mode and then spectating them.